# How To Copy All Lines of Memo String to DBGrid Fields

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to to copy all lines of string in memo to dbgrid fields (Fields FREKUENSI_TPOKOK). I have tried the following :

```
procedure Tfrm_csbo.cmd_copyClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  tpokok: string;
  i: integer;
    Begin
      tbl_LLOANP.First;
      for i := 0 to Memo2.Lines.Count-1 do
      tpokok := 'UPDATE LLOANP SET FREKUENSI_TPOKOK = ' + Memo2.Lines[i];
      qr_LLOANP.Close;
      qr_LLOANP.SQL.Clear;
      qr_LLOANP.SQL.Add(tpokok);
      qr_LLOANP.ExecSQL;
    end
end;
```

but the result is not as i expected to be.

Answer (score 0):

If we indent your code properly then it looks like this:

```
tbl_LLOANP.First;
for i := 0 to Memo2.Lines.Count-1 do
  tpokok := 'UPDATE LLOANP SET FREKUENSI_TPOKOK = ' + Memo2.Lines[i];
qr_LLOANP.Close;
qr_LLOANP.SQL.Clear;
qr_LLOANP.SQL.Add(tpokok);
qr_LLOANP.ExecSQL;
```

So you execute a single SQL statement, rather than one per item. Perhaps you meant to write:

```
tbl_LLOANP.First;
for i := 0 to Memo2.Lines.Count-1 do
begin
  tpokok := 'UPDATE LLOANP SET FREKUENSI_TPOKOK = ' + Memo2.Lines[i];
  qr_LLOANP.Close;
  qr_LLOANP.SQL.Clear;
  qr_LLOANP.SQL.Add(tpokok);
  qr_LLOANP.ExecSQL;
end;
```

Do note that you are opening yourself up to SQL injection here. You should always use SQL parameters rather than build your own queries from user supplied data.

Comment: i have try your suggestion above, but the result is still zero values for all the rows (fields) in FREKUENSI_TPOKOK, the main idea is that i want to copy all the lines in TMEMO and paste into dbgrid, where DBGRID rows count (Field FREKUENSI_TPOKOK) = TMEMO lines count.
Is there any way around on how to do copy paste TMEMO Lines to dbgrid rows (fields)?

Comment: I just fixed the Pascal. I don't know anything about your database.